# How to delete a specific cached unity asset bundle?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hi I was wondering if it is possible to delete specific cache instead deleting all cached asset bundle using `Caching.CleanCache`. Any suggestion if it is possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CleanCache is deprecated, use ClearCache to clear all asset bundles.

To remove asset bundle with all cached versions, **you can use**:

```
Caching.ClearAllCachedVersions("YourCachedAssetBundleName");
```

this will removes all the cached versions of the given AssetBundle from the cache or use. (P.S "YourCachedAssetBundleName" must not contain dot '.')

```
Caching.ClearCachedVersion("YourCachedAssetBundleName", hash);
```

Removes the given version of the AssetBundle.